# Using SVN from a Unix shell doesn't recognise vars

Tags: svn, shell

In a Unix shell I try the following:

```
svn_checkout_dir="svn"
svn add "$svn_server" "$svn_checkout_dir/save"
```

: but the "$svn_checkout_dir/save" will not resolve to "svn/save". Am I using this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to export the `svn_checkout_dir` before calling svn:

```
export svn_checkout_dir="svn"
svn add "$svn_server" "$svn_checkout_dir/save"
```

If you don't do that, `svn_checkout_dir` is only a local variable, not an environment variable visible to the `svn` process. So, in your case (assuming that `svn_checkout_dir` and `svn_server` are defined the same way), your call evaluates to

```
svn add "" "/save"
```

as long as you don't `export` `svn_server` and `svn_checkout_dir`.

If you put your two lines into a script however, it would work as expected since within the script, `svn_checkout_dir` is visible as local variable (and overrides a possibly existent environment variable with the same name).